# D3 stacked bar chart with time

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, stackedbarseries

I have problem working with d3 and date time.
Is there an example that shows stacked bar chart with time dimension ? 
I would like to visualize users' activities such as riding on a bus, walking, etc. as a bar chart. 
The existing ones are based on numbers and really complicated to understand. I found this one https://gist.github.com/anotherjavadude/2940908 which seems better, but still not clear for me.

Comment: You should be able to do that quite easily with [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have switch to HTML5. I think d3 is not good for none standard charts. It is designed to support standard visualizations and it is hard to change its predefined template. At least now I am more comfortable with pure HTML 5

Comment: This is wrong, there is no pre-defined template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Stacked bar-charts on time scale using D3](http://bl.ocks.org/anupsavvy/9513382) which seems to fit your needs.

Anyways, I'd rather go with [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) and use its stacked bar charts as time series.

On the JSfiddle below you can see exactly how I did it:

http://jsfiddle.net/fwuensche/y1w9nnod/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'My energy consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 
                         'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Consumption [KWh]'
            },
            stackLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                }
            }
        },

        // series data goes here

    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bar chart example based on date: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this example and try to understand it. It is too complicated for a beginner to learn.